# When to use the "meaning" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I am bit puzzled about the usage of the [meaning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) tag, because we also have [word-meaning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning) and [meaning-in-context](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context). The definitions of the two latter seem to describe subsets of what the [meaning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) tag applies to.

So my question is: when we have a question that matches the definition of [word-meaning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning) or [meaning-in-context](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context), should we also tag it with [meaning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning)?

Comment: I like how this question has the [tag:tags] and [tag:tagging] tags, which seem to have exactly the same issue.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu Congrats! I wondered from the start whether someone would notice that ;-)

Comment: And … they are merged.

Answer (score 5):

From the [tag wiki](https://german.stackexchange.com/tags/word-meaning/info) of [word-meaning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning):

> This tag should be used for questions asking about **nuances of meaning** and definitions of a specific word. […]
>
> If you are asking about the definitions or **nuances of words**, phrases or even sentences, please use the broader [meaning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) instead.

I do not understand where the difference is and moreover where it should matter. Tags do not exist for their own sake but to ease searching or allow interested people to subscribe to them. I thus opt for synonymising [word-meaning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning) to [meaning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning).

I could imagine that somebody is particularly interested in answering [meaning-in-context](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) questions, and thus I would not synonymise to [meaning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning). I would apply both tags for questions that are asking from a specific context but also about the general meaning of a word.

Comment: Thank you! Side effect of your answer: I learned about the tag wiki. Apparently it is so hidden that I didn't ever notice it before, but at least not hidden enough that I could not find it myself after your hint.

Comment: Ich kann mich nur noch schwach erinnern. Wir haben damals eine ganze Reihe an Tags dokumentiert, gelöscht, synonym gemacht etc. Auf jeden Fall sind "Meaning" und "Word-meaning" für mich nicht wirkich synonym. Man fragt nicht immer nach der Bedeutung eines Wortes, sondern vielleicht auch einer Phrase, einer Redewendung oder weiß der Geier. Da man aber nicht für alles und jedes ein einzelnen Tag machen will, war glaub ich damals die Idee, dass "meaning" als globaler Tag genutzt wird, wenn es nicht um ein Wort geht. Umgesetzt wurde es in der Weise selten. Oft werden beide parallel verwendet.

Comment: Hmm, ich verstehe jetzt, wo der Unterschied liegen soll, aber nicht so wirklich, welchen Vorteil es hat, diesen auch in Tags zu haben. Wann würde jemand ausschließlich eines der beiden Tags abonnieren oder ausschließlich nach einem der beiden Tags suchen wollen? Und selbst wenn, ist dieser Fall hinreichend häufig um den Aufwand zu rechtfertigen, die beiden Tags auseinanderzuhalten?

Comment: The current situation looks a bit "halfway-done". [tag:word-meaning] still exists and is a synonym to [tag:meaning]. Its description, however, still tells you when to use one and the other, which looks silly, because for new taggings you always end up with meaning. Also, I still see a separate counter for the word-meaning tag badge, which I will never be able to get, since there won't be new questions for this tag. Wouldn't it be better to merge [tag:word-meaning] and  [tag:meaning]?

Comment: @Matthias: I only synonymised the tags first, in case we decided to undo this (which is nearly impossible for merges). By now, they can safely be merged, what I did. As for the tag info, I simply forgot it.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thank you!